# Windows 2008 R2 server managing application

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We are looking for one or more application(s) that can help us with the following:

Send an email alert:

- when there is warning/error in the event logs
- when remaining hard disk space is less than 10%
- when someone logs in using RDP
- when a firewall port is opened

Regards,

Paul

Comment: "When a firewall port is opened" as in when a new connection is created, or when something edits the Windows firewall to add a new port to exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a monitoring system. There are thousands to choose from, both paid and free/open-source. Google is your friend.